# user defined x-header doesnt send to api problem

Tags: react-native, xmlhttprequest, axios, fetch

user defined x-header doesnt send to api problem

We have a rest api configured with cors. We can access it with ajax, swift etc.

But when we try to send request from android with react-native application x-header doesnt sent in request header. Our parameters added as miscellaneous header and not sent to server.

We try to request with axios and fetch and xmlHttpRequest

By the way when we try the same request with react it works.

My environment:

android,
react-native,
axios,
fetch
xmlHttpRequest

[image: sending params]
[image: code example]

Comment: I see the `x-userzone` header in your first capture, so I'm not sure I understand from where came this capture. Could you explain what is it ?

Comment: X-userzone my user defined header that I want to send it to my api. But it doesnt going